# Приложение с запросом к серверу выдает NetworkOnMainThreadException, без использования сети в главном потоке

Tags: java, android, get, httpclient, okhttp

Пишу приложение с запросом к моему серверу на библиотеке okhttp3, тело ответа помещается в текстовое поле. При запросе выдаёт исключение сети в главном потоке, хотя весь сетевой код находится в параллельном потоке. Я не понимаю суть ошибки (хочу объяснения), но одно из предложений решения проблемы на этом сайте - делать запрос через enqueue().  Можно ли решить проблему, не прибегая к enqueue()?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OkHttpClient client;
    private Request request;
    private TextView jsonTv;
    private Button requestButton;

    private static final String ADDRESS = "http://123.123.1.23:8080/api/v1/data";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jsonTv = findViewById(R.id.json_tv);
        requestButton = findViewById(R.id.request_button);


        requestButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AsyncRequest asyncRequest = new AsyncRequest();
            asyncRequest.execute();
        }
    };

    class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Response>{

        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            client = new OkHttpClient();

            HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(ADDRESS).newBuilder();

            HttpUrl httpUrl = httpUrlBuilder.build();

            request = new Request.Builder().url(httpUrl).build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                return response;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            try {
                super.onPostExecute(response);


                /*исключение на строке ниже*/
                JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                jsonTv.setText(String.valueOf(rootArray));

            }
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Лень искать доки, но где-то в этой цепочке `response.body().string()` выполняется загрузка данных с сервера (та самая сетевая операция). Да и в любом случае разбор ответа тоже следует делать в фоне и выдавать оттуда готовый ответ (строку или `JSONArray` или что вы там хотите по итогу получить)

Comment: Попробуйте строки `    private OkHttpClient client;
    private Request request;` перенести в класс `AsyncRequest `

Comment: `try - catch (IOException e)` как бы намекает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет правильнее.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    ...

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        return response.body().string();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Но вообще лучше пользоваться асинхронными вызовами.
https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/retrofit-sync-async-calls/

Comment: Спасибо за код. Но разве, если я не помещу execute() в параллельный поток, запрос не будет асинхронным? Я же когда на кнопку жму у меня система не "замерзает". Даже в указанном вами источнике написано, что интерфейс блокируется, чего я у своего приложения не наблюдаю. Я неопытный, если что поправьте. @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: Поправка:
 Но разве, если я помещу execute() в параллельный поток, запрос не будет асинхронным?*

Comment: Тело ответа скачивается только при вызове `string()`, потому как до этого неизвестно в каком виде вы его хотите получить (`charStream()`, `byteStream()`, `bytes()` или `string()`) и как использовать, при том что контент может быть огромным файлом, который вообще не уместится ни в какую память. Вы не наблюдаете блокировку UI потому что фреймворк не позволяет вам это сделать, выбрасывая исключение. Хотя при стабильной сети и мизерных объёмах данных зависаний тоже могло не быть, но поведение сети не предсказуемо, поэтому было решено запретить любые сетевые операции в UI-потоке вообще.

Comment: @woesss, cпасибо вам за объяснение ошибки, есть еще один вопрос: то есть если я поправлю код, на то, что мне предложили выше (ошибка пропала и вроде как теперь нету сетевых операций в главном потоке) запрос всё равно будет синхронным или всё таки асинхронным? Просто насколько я понимаю, enqueue() делает поток за программиста и в нем уже происходит вся мишура, а я делал поток вручную. Мне указали, что у меня синхронный запрос, правда это или нет, я так и не понял.

Comment: Всё относительно. Запрос у вас будет синхронный относительно библиотеки и фонового потока - она выполняет его в вызывающем потоке и возвращает результат в него же, при этом другие задачи в этом потоке не могут быть выполнены, поэтому вызов ещё называют блокирующим. Но на уровне приложения запрос уже асинхронный, так как вы его переводите в другой поток с помощью `AsyncTask`. Асинхронный означает что вызывающий поток передаёт задачу другому потоку и занимается своими делами. Рабочий поток по завершению задачи перекидывает результат в нужный поток с помощью колбека

Comment: @woesss Прошу прощения за приставучесть, но какие задачи? Можете пожалуйста привести примеры?

Comment: Примеры чего? Есть задача получить данные с сервера, есть задача обработать клик по кнопке, перекрасить ей фон, чтобы было видно, что она нажата и много других. Если UI поток пойдёт в сеть и там застрянет, то кто покрасит кнопку? Можете представить себе программу как офис, потоки - люди, каждый выполняет свою задачу. Главный поток - начальник, ставит задачи другим: сбегать в другой отдел, принести ему бумажку. Если он пойдёт сам, то не сможет отвечать на звонки (обработка событий, ака клик по кнопке) - получится "приложение не отвечает", то есть не реагирует на внешние команды.